# xp_cmdshell: should it ever be used?

Tags: databases, sql-injection

Can *xp_cmdshell* ever be used safely within a stored proc and are there any situations for which there really is no other option? In other words, should its usage within a stored proc always be flagged as a security issue (as is advised by a well-known source code analyzer)?

Put differently, would you agree with the following statement (direct quote)?

> The function *xp_cmdshell* cannot be used safely.  It should not be used.

Comment: For those unfamiliar "xp_cmdshell", it is "an extended stored procedure provided by Microsoft and stored in the master database. This procedure allows you to issue operating system commands directly to the Windows command shell via T-SQL code."  Yikes!!

Comment: No, I don't agree.  It absolutely can be used safely using at least 2 different methods that I know of and one of them is pretty darned easy to setup.  The problem is that BOL doesn't actually tell you how to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is always a *risk*. It should always be *reviewed*. It can be properly *mitigated*.

There are legitimate uses, sometimes necessities, but watch your input closely!

Comment: What of the problem that there is no way to limit a user to a predefined group of operations and so therefore any privilege grant allows the user to execute any command string, i.e. it doesn't allow granularity of privilage or stated different any control becomes complete control?

Comment: Now, SQL Server is a secondary for me, so tell me if I'm wrong: Granting a user execute permissions on the stored procedure allows that procedure to be run by them. It does not allow them to modify it, and it doesn't entail granting permissions for everything used by that stored procedure. If they must be granted `xp_cmdshell` permissions to run a stored procedure that contains it, then you've definitely got an issue. I'm reasonably confident that is not required -- the procedure should not be owned by the regular user.

Comment: Don't forget that xp_cmdshell is running under the same permissions as the SQL service account.  If the account is less privileged you have a relatively smaller attack surface.

Comment: True, I think this is going the way I thought it would. I was supried to hear the quoted (in the question) reasoning (from a relatively respected source) and thought I'd play devils advocate so make sure I wasn't missing something!

Comment: @TobyS... thats the problem with those sorts of statements. Short answer: xp_cmdshell is evil.  Long answer: it depends. ;)

Comment: @SteveS - current version of MSSQL allow you to set a *different* OS account to run xp_cmdshell commands under.

Comment: @JeffFerland... you wrote "I'm reasonably confident that is not required -- the procedure should not be owned by the regular user."  That's 100% correct.  There's no need for the user to even know if a table is involved never mind xp_CmdShell.  And yes, it's quite easy to setup.

Comment: @AvID can that user be disabled?

Comment: @Ori yes, I dont see why not - it's a regular OS user. What would be the point of that though?

Answer (score 12):

Turning off xp_CmdShell is a bit like putting a veil over rotting meat. It brings a false sense of security to the table and the flies can still get at the meat. Allow me to explain.

Who can use xp_CmdShell? That's right. Only people/app logins with "SA" privs or people that you made the horrible mistake of granting a proxy to can use it.

Next question. If you have xp_CmdShell turned off, who are the only people that can turn it back on? Correct again! Only people/apps with "SA" privs can turn it back on.

So, what's the real issue with xp_CmdShell being a security risk? The answer is xp_CmdShell is NOT a security risk. Poor security is the only security risk. If a hacker or an malicious internal user get's into the system with "SA" privs, then they can turn xp_CmdShell on in momements. Yeah, that action gets logged but that only provides documented testimony that security was grossly lacking to begin with.

Turning xp_CmdShell off does nothing for security except to provide a chance for that part of a hackers code to turn it back on to run.

I'll say it again. xp_CmdShell is not a security risk. Only bad security is a security risk. Fix your security and then turn on xp_CmdShell. It's a wonderful tool and you're missing out on it because of bad security practices and myth.

Comment: I completely agree with you, Jeff. An attacker who gained syadmin privileges could create a SQL Agent job owned by sa with a CmdExec jobstep and achieve the same as xp_cmdshell. He could also create a CLR stored procedure that starts a process. How would that be different from xp_cmdshell? Securing the server properly is the only way to prevent security risks.

Comment: Ah, my ol' friend.  Thank you for the feedback.  Good to "see" you again.

Comment: +1 you are wrong, but I like that you are wrong because you are encouraging people to be less secure, which inturn makes the interest a more fun place.  Yes Install SQL Server on everything, and yes the extra part about how it is easy to fix with configuration.  Love it <3. Its 2020 and 9/10 SQL Servers are not going to be hardened correctly - but of course blame the DB admin XD

Comment: Heh... I'll give you the same plus one for being wrong.  I wish I could give you a plus for being wrong in thinking that disabling xp_CmdShell does anything at all to "harden" a server.  It just doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

"With great power comes great responsibility."   That being said, I  think `xp_cmdshell` is one of the worst security train wreaks to make it out of Redmond.

Edit: 2020, as a penetration tester for 10+ years - `xp_cmdshell` still one of the most terrifying security risks I have encountered because it has a the best combination of; being wide spread, used by important business like banks, and maximum impact.   SQLmap can be used to get SA and re-enable xp_cmdshell... using only SQL Injection in a webapp.

As one engineer to another, Thank you Microsoft - I literally could not have gotten these shells without you.

Comment: I know it's an old question, but I really have to say it: I'm surprised 3 people took your trolling seriously enough to upvote your answer.

Comment: @spaghettidba I am dead serious, as a pentester `xp_cmdshell()` is a god send.  What makes it so bad is that no one at Microsoft even thinks to fix this issue.  I'm very happy to encounter Microsoft products and applications built on the Microsoft platform because they are weak.  Fun fact,  my first 0-day was in a Microsoft security product when I was 16,  which was more than a decade ago.

Comment: @rook - It's not often that I get to talk to a real PEN tester so I've got to take this opportunity to ask (not looking for a fight... I'm honestly and truly interested in your good experience), if you CAN'T get into someone's goodie locker with SysAdmin privs, have you still been able to use xp_CmdShell as an attacker even if it's enabled?  If so, is there a way to protect against it?

Comment: @Jeff Moden. _YES_,  so sqlmap does this quite well. Even if you are not SA - because of query stacking you can login to the SA account using a SQL QUERY - yes an injected sql query can be used to gain SA and then re-enable any command.  You still need to know the password... but it can be brute-forced and if this attack wasn't taken into consideration  then the SA account could have a weak password... and i have seen this happen many times, even at banks.   Not a SQL-Server expert but i think there is hardening that can prevent this attack... but not default !!!!  SQLMap for the win!

Answer (score 4):

I think "it should not be used" is probably pretty good advice.  That's not a categorical "It's *always* insecure", but rather a recognition that xp_cmdshell is dangerous and any use of it is grounds for concern and careful scrutiny.

And even if you think you know how to avoid the security risks, xp_cmdshell is still probably not the best tool to use.  Odds are that there is a better solution (one which also, fortuitously happens to be less risky).

Answer (score 3):

What kind of security is being used in your SQL Server environment, Mixed or Integrated (Windows)?  How many are in the sysadmin SQL Server role?  MS best practices call for Integrated authentication (no sa login, no SQL logins) and only two in the sysadmin SQL Server role.  I submit that following these best practices greatly mitigates one's exposure.  Further, xp_cmdshell (pre sqlcmd mode and pre-Powershell) gives the ability to copy transaction log files from the production server to the DR server hundreds of miles away from within a scheduled SQL Agent job.
No evil here but as the one poster put, "it depends".

Answer (score 2):

To emphasize jl01's answer (which I gave a +1 to)...

Oddly enough, a good measure of a properly secured and safe SQL Server is to actually have xp_CmdShell enabled.  What I mean by that is that if your system is secure enough, you shouldn't have to worry about trivial matters like xp_CmdShell being enabled AND USED.

Especially as of SQL Server 2005, there is virtually no reason why any users other than DBA's should have privs greater than PUBLIC privs and EXECUTE privs on stored procedures in a properly locked down system.  In fact, implemented correctly, users with PUBLIC privs should be able to execute a stored procedure that contains calls to xp_CmdShell without being able to run xp_CmdShell directly themselves.

I think it ironic that MS created the command shell proxy to allow low priv users to run xp_CmdShell directly when they shouldn't even be able to see a table.